# Bug in Ionic Native File Plugin - {“code”:5,”message”:”ENCODING_ERR”}

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I’m running the following code with Ionic Native File Plugin:

```
  accessFile(path, fileName) {
    return this.file.readAsDataURL(path, fileName).then((result) => {
      return result;
    }).catch(err => console.log('readAsDataURL Error', JSON.stringify(err)));
  }
```

I’m getting this error:

> readAsDataURL Error {“code”:5,“message”:“ENCODING_ERR”}

I’m using WKWebView and here’s my Ionic Info:

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0 
@ionic/app-scripts : 1.3.12
Cordova Platforms  : ios 4.5.4
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
ios-deploy : 1.9.2 
Node       : v8.11.1
npm        : 5.6.0 
OS         : macOS High Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 9.4.1 Build version 9F2000
```

Working on iOS.

I’ve tried the Path with `file:///` and without it, both ways still give the same error.

My Path looks like this:

```
file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E9…D/tmp/
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I also encountered this issue but found no solution.

Comment: I got it to work, please see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

By trial and error I got the answer. You need to get rid of the `/private/` and keep `file://`, so that your path goes like `file:///var/.....`. I’m getting this path from Video Editor after transcoding and trimming the video, so this case maybe unique. Also to point out, according to Ionic guide for transfer from UIWebView to WKWebView `file://` is no longer needed, which is clearly not the case here.